# QtCreator failing to step into 3rd party library source during debug (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, gdb, cmake, qt-creator

I'm having some trouble stepping into functions of the OpenCV library during debugging while using QtCreator.

My configuration:

Ubuntu 11.04

OpenCV 2.3.1 (built from source using Cmake)

QtCreator 2.1.0/2.3.0

Cmake 2.8.3

I'm linking from my own project to the OpenCV dlls. My C++ App is built specifying a debug build with the line below in my CMakeLists.txt:

`set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)`

I've specified the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE as Debug during Cmake configuration of OpenCV. I tried rebuilding everything from source, making sure the Cmake debug flags are set correctly for OpenCV. I tried QtCreator Versions 2.1.0 and 2.3.0 without any change in behavior.

Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: Can you step into OpenCV dll using gdb only (without QtCreator)? Do OpenCV  symbols loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, I can step into the OpenCV dll's source invoking gdb from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 7 years would you be willing to consider updated software?

If yes, then with:

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Cmake 3.11.2
Qt-Creator 4.5
OpenCV 3.2

you can step into the OpenCV library while debugging!